# Install unixodbc-dev in Ubuntu 20

Tags: ubuntu, odbc, unixodbc

I am trying to install pdo_sqlsrv in ubuntu 20.04, when I try apt-get install unixodbc-dev I get:

```
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 unixodbc-dev : Depende: unixodbc (= 2.3.7)
                Depende: odbcinst1debian2 (= 2.3.7) pero 2.3.6-0.1build1 va a ser instalado
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.
```

apt policy libodbc1:

```
libodbc1:
  Instalados: 2.3.7
  Candidato:  2.3.7
  Tabla de versión:
 *** 2.3.7 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/19.10/prod eoan/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.3.6-0.1build1 500
        500 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages

apt policy odbcinst1debian2
odbcinst1debian2:
  Instalados: 2.3.6-0.1build1
  Candidato:  2.3.7
  Tabla de versión:
     2.3.7 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/19.10/prod eoan/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.3.6-0.1build1 500
        500 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Thank you

Comment: It appears that when your machine hit packages.microsoft.com it received an HTTP status 500 which means "Internal Server Error". Give Microsoft a chance to fix the problem with their server and then try again.

Comment: Unfortunately Sql Server is a requirement of my client. I am not a fun of Microsoft, Sqlserver is the most complex connection that I have to do including Oracle.